# Using the SMALL function in excel, issues with IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to obtain the highest and the lowest values within a data set and record each instance. I have used the following spreadsheet to do this.

I want to obtain the lowest occurrence and if there are one or more values that are the same it will list those values too. However, when I use what I have I cant get the numbers to stop listing.

I am Assuming this is because The numbers are not the same exact values to the number of decimal places the original data comes from. e.g. the lowest value is 21.5 but the raw data gives it to 21.498 etc.

I tried using the Round function but it merely changes the formatting of the cell.

Has anyone found a way around this?

*Edit*****
I only want to report the lowest value, and if there are multiple occurrences of the same number (to one decimal place) then record those as well. The issue is that I don't know how to tell excel to stop the list if the values are the same to 1 decimal place. I tried the round function but it only changes the formatting of the cell not the actual number so excel thinks they are different values. I am not sure how to get this to work.

G3 is the top cell with `=IFERROR(SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A3),"")` in it.

```
=IFERROR(SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A3),"")

=IFERROR(IF(SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A4)=G3,"",SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A4)),"")
```

the data is;

[image]

And I need the highest and lowest data to 1 decimal place.

Comment: I do not understand what is the problem here? The formula you gave is able to find the lowest temperatures and I guess you simply switch to **LARGE** to find the highest temperatures. Then you can use **INDEX+MATCH** to return the corresponding serial number.  If you want to show the temperatures to 1 decimal place, you can simply highlight data in column G and J and format them to show 1 decimal place. It is quite easy and straight forward?

Comment: Hi, I only want to report the lowest value, and if there are multiple occurrences of the same number (to one decimal place) then record those as well. The issue is that I don't know how to tell excel to stop the list if the values are the same to 1 decimal place. I tried the round function but it only changes the formatting of the cell not the actual number so excel thinks they are different values.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

G3:

```
=IFERROR(ROUND(SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A3);1),"")
```

From G4 onwards:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROUND(SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A4);1)=G$3,"",ROUND(SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A4);1)),"")
```

Comment: Hi, excel does not like me using the ; in the code, and when I change it to , it doesnt work?

Comment: Just change them to regular commas instead, that should fix it

Comment: I did this but it still lists the values regardless of whether the numbers are the same to 1 decimal place? do you know how to tell excel to stop the list if the values are the same to 1 decimal place. I tried the round function but it only changes the formatting of the cell not the actual number so excel thinks they are different values.

Comment: ROUND does not just change the formatting of the cell, it actually transforms the value. The important step here is to have ROUND in the reference cell G3, the formulas I posted above are tested and work fine. If you continue to have problems please post the formulas you are currently using so I can take a look at those.

Comment: I see the issue, the IF statement logic was just the inverse of what I needed, I used this and it worked; =IFERROR(IF(ROUND(SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A4),1)=I$3,ROUND(SMALL($C$3:$C$101,A4),1),""),"")    Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Array function (entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=SMALL(ROUND($C$3:$C$20,1),A3)
```

And for the matching serial number:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$20,MATCH(SMALL($C$3:$C$20,A3),$C$3:$C$20,0))
```

Here are the results (formatted with 3 decimal places just to prove the values are properly rounded):

[image]